# Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object. using data from the server

Tags: sql, ms-access

What the following code is supposed to be doing is taking each record from [ICBC] table and look for a matching in the [CIC TT Payment] table. But it is giving me a "Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object" type of error. Any idea on how to solve that?

```
    SELECT [CIC TT Payment].*, ICBC.*
    FROM ICBC INNER JOIN [CIC TT Payment]
    ON (ICBC.[贷方发生额] Between [CIC TT Payment].Monthly_Amt+200 And [CIC TT Payment].Monthly_Amt-200)
    AND ((ICBC.[个性化信息] Like "*" & [CIC TT Payment].Plate & "*")
    Or (ICBC.[个性化信息] Like "*" & [CIC TT Payment].Contract & "*"))
    AND ([CIC TT Payment].Contact_Date BETWEEN  DateAdd("d",-2,[ICBC].[交易时间]) AND DateAdd("d",2,[ICBC].[交易时间]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying a *Left* on the memo field:

```
SELECT [CIC TT Payment].*, ICBC.*
FROM ICBC INNER JOIN [CIC TT Payment]
ON (ICBC.[贷方发生额] Between [CIC TT Payment].Monthly_Amt+200 And [CIC TT Payment].Monthly_Amt-200)
AND ((Left(ICBC.[个性化信息],255) Like "*" & [CIC TT Payment].Plate & "*")
Or (Left(ICBC.[个性化信息],255) Like "*" & [CIC TT Payment].Contract & "*"))
AND ([CIC TT Payment].Contact_Date BETWEEN  DateAdd("d",-2,[ICBC].[交易时间]) AND DateAdd("d",2,[ICBC].[交易时间]));
```